# Get url string in PreRequestHandlerExecute in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, httpmodule

I have a class that implements IHTTPModule which handles the event PreRequestHandlerExecute. In the method of that event i want to get the url of the page that executed the call.

So for instance if i have a SignOn.aspx page, which then redirects to an Index.aspx page, in my method i want to be able to get the SignOn.aspx url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a redirect, you should find the page where the request came from in the

[`Request.UrlReferrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)

This property gives the information from the [Referer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) http header.